# Creating a console based text game and can't get the cursor to pop up a line into the proper location (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, string, terminal, console

Edit: using the Paint gem.

So I'm re-writing the shop system in my text based game I made in ruby. I'm attempting to get multiple colors onto a single line of text. I found a method that works but for some reason the first string (which includes the item id and the item name) is getting concated at 11 characters all the time.

each item value is an array. value[0] contains the name, and so on.

Here is the code that draws each item for the shop menu:

```
shopbag.each { |id, value|
        if id != 0
          string1 = "(" + id.to_s + ")" + " " + value[0]; str1 = string1.size
          string2 = "ATTACK: #{value[1]}"; str2 = string2.size
          string3 = "SPEED: #{value[2]}"; str3 = string3.size
          pa string1; pa "\033[1A \033[#{str1}C #{string2}", :red, :bright; pa "\033[1A \033[#{str2}C #{string3}", :green, :bright
        end
      }
```

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:
[shop bug (click for image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqjfu.png)

Note you can see a string size before each item, as I had a print line in there to verify that the size was correct. It is not present in my code snippet here. If it was working properly, it would show the full names before the attack and speed values.

Comment: I'm baffled why you are using ASCII cursor controls in this way, but strictly speaking the problem is your third print (`SPEED`) only moves the length of `string1` to the right instead of the length of both previous strings. The escape should be `\033[#{str1+str2}C`

Comment: @rmlockerd can I ask why thats baffling? thats what I was able to find for hopping up a line in order to draw text with another color. The paint gem does support multicolor strings but Ive never been able to make it work with more than two, and there are cases where I dont want part of the line to be drawn. BTW, with your advice I was able to fix it. I still cant figure out how to flag your post as the answer though. I know theres supposed to be a checkbox next to your post but I don't see it.